# FireFox Addon getElementById on http-on-examine-response didn't return any value

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, getelementbyid, xpcom, content-script

I am trying to get a value from an element in active page on http-on-examine-response. My below script works well as an addon without lines between

```
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
```

and

```
contentScript: contentScriptString
```

But when I add those lines it access the text file but doesn't write Anything. I can't see any error message in console because I don't use SDK because the new SDK uses complex things which I have to learn more on this. (For Now I just edit js file in components folder and update chrome.manifest and install.rdf if any and zip them then rename it as xpi and open it in firefox and it works well). I googled how to debug this script with which sdk and tried many scripts titled 'getelementbyid firefox addon' and had no luck. It would be helpful even if you say which sdk should use (a dumb question. But couldnt help myself).

```
Components.utils.import('resource://gre/modules/XPCOMUtils.jsm');
function GetCity() {
var GetCity = {
observe: function(subject, topic, data) {
  if (topic == "http-on-examine-response") {
    var httpChannel = subject.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIHttpChannel);
    if (httpChannel.responseStatusText == "OK")
    {
    var buffer =  httpChannel.URI.spec;
      var pw = buffer.search("mywebsite.com/release");
      if (pw > 0)
      {
      var date = new Date();
      var TimeStamp = date.toLocaleString();
      var pfum = buffer.search("flag=release1");
      if (pfum > 0 )
      {
      var flagname = "1";
      var flagnum = 4;
      }
      var pfuk = buffer.search("flag=release2");
      if (pfuk > 0 )
      {
      var flagname = "2";
      var flagnum = "1";
      }
      var pfup = buffer.search("flag=release3");
      if (pfup > 0 )
      {
      var flagname = "3";
      var flagnum = 2;
      }
      var pfap = buffer.search("flag=release4");
      if (pfap > 0 )
      {
      var flagname = "4";
      var flagnum = 3;
      }
      if (flagnum > 0)
      {
      var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
      var contentScriptString = 'var cityname = document.getElementById("city").value ;'
      tabs.activeTab.attach({
      contentScript: contentScriptString
      });
      buffer += "^" + ThisUserName + "^" + ThisComputerName + "^" + TimeStamp + "^" + flagname + "\r\n";
      fos.write(buffer, buffer.length);
      }
      }
  }
}
}
};
var nsIEnvironment = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/process/environment;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIEnvironment);
var ThisUserName = nsIEnvironment.get("UserName");
var ThisComputerName = nsIEnvironment.get("ComputerName");

var FileUtils = Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm").FileUtils;

var d = new Date();
var dd = d.getDate();
if (dd < 10)
dd = "0" + dd;
var mm = (d.getMonth()+1);
if (mm < 10)
mm = "0" + mm;
var yyyy = d.getFullYear();


  var file = new FileUtils.File( "T:\\-\\CityList\\" + yyyy + "\\" + mm + "\\" + dd );
  if (!file.exists()) {
  file.create(file.DIRECTORY_TYPE, 0755);
  }
  var filename = "HM_" + ThisUserName + yyyy + "-" + mm + "-" + dd + ".txt";
  file.append(filename);

var fos = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/file-output-stream;1"]
                  .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIFileOutputStream);
// PR_WRONLY | PR_CREATE_FILE | PR_APPEND
fos.init(file, 0x02 | 0x08 | 0x10, -1, 0);

var observerService = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/observer-service;1"]
                              .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIObserverService);
observerService.addObserver(HotelMappingCounter, "http-on-examine-response", false);
}

var NSGetFactory = XPCOMUtils.generateNSGetFactory([CityList]);
```

Comment: So this observer is getting you like the html of a page? You want to now parse that html? Or do you want to act on the content in the tab, meaning act on the website?

Comment: @Noitidart: yes. I want to parse that html if it means that 'var cityname = document.getElementById("city").value ;' will work.

Comment: I kind of asked two questions and you said "yes" haha. But maybe I think what you what is `nsIDOMParser` see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser and here: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[firefox-addon]+nsIDOMParser

Comment: haha. I did a fun thing and like your humor sense. I tried to reply in an agreeable way. well. I will see the links you gave. Thank you for your support Noitidart.